# Iterate over a text label in HTML using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

For my graph in Highcharts I would like to be able to select only some labels for the x-axis to be plotted.

Example: I have a x-axis time for 24 hours `[8:15,8:30,8:45...8:00]` and I would like to select only those times `[8:00,9:00,10:00...]`

The HTML code of Highcharts seems like this:

```
<g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels" zIndex="7">

    <text x="42.40625" style="color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="346" opacity="1"></text>
    <text x="59.21875" style="color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="346" opacity="1">

        10:00

    </text>
    <text x="76.03125" style="color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="346" opacity="1">

        10:15

    </text>
    <text x="92.84375" style="color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="346" opacity="1"></text>
```

Per day there are 96 time values.

Until now I did this (this extracts only the first text (10:00)):

```
var test = $('g.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-axis-labels text').html();
```

So the question is how can I iterate over all text labels?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to set [`tickInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) to one hour?

Comment: Thx. for your effort. It would not work, because the time is not static. It moves in the x-axis its position.

Comment: I don't understand your response. TickInterval set fixed interval between ticks, so if it would be 1h, then you will get rid off that extra labels.

Comment: Each x value has one y value. Let's say: [(1,00:00),(2,00:15),(3,00:30)...(96,23:45)]. The time (x-axis) refers to the last 24 hours and the y-axis updates its value constantly. Just imaging a train passing by in front of your window (it changes the view of the train). It my case, I have watt_consumption vs time. I am plotting in "real-time" this graph. TickInterval based its calculation on the first value in the x-axis.

Comment: Could you create jsfiddle demo to show the idea and issue? I will check then.

Comment: With all of your explanations, it still seems that tickInterval is all you need here. (or possibly tickPositions, if it's more complex than it seems) Have you tried it? Set up a fiddle and explain what's not working and/or show how you want it to work.

Comment: Thank you guys for your effort. I found a solution, just modifying the code in HTML (setting the opacity attribute to zero). I really don't know how to represent this in a fiddle. [ 7:00, 8:00, 9:00 ...23:00... 6:00 ], the next 15min. [8:00, 9:00...23:00...7:00]. Anyway thxs.

Comment: Whatever works for you I guess. But it seems a really silly way to accomplish something for which there is most likely a built in option.  As far as a fiddle goes - just put your chart in a fiddle so we can see what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), and filter the whole hours:

```
var labels = jQuery('text').filter(function() {
    var regex = /[0-9]+\:00/;
    return regex.test($(this).text());
});

console.log(labels);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdfy02L2/)